# SGMII to 100BASE-FX

Tags: sgmii

I need to connect seventh port (SGMII) of KSZ9477S switch to AFBR5803AQZ optical transceiver (It's 100 Mbps). I wanted to use PHY with SGMII interface and fiber mode (VSC8658XHJ), but it's too expensive. I also found 88e1111 Marvell IC which should be able to convert SGMII to fiber interface, but it seems that it converts only to 1000BASE-FX while I need 100BASE-FX. Can somebody give me a clue how can I  connect SGMII port of KSZ9477S switch IC to AFBR5803AQZ optical transceiver using cheaper solution?

Comment: If the IC converts 1000 Base FX, it should also convert 100 Base FX, look for register settings in datasheet. Please add datasheet link, I will try to look as well.

Comment: Thank you for the response!) Here is the link to the datasheet [link](http://www.cexiinc.com/cexilib/CEXI_CAD_Footprint_Data/PDF's/Desc/MV-S100649-00H_88E1111_Datasheet.pdf)

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, there is not anything called as 1000BASE-FX  and even Marvell IC doesn't show anything for 100BASE-FX. Sorry for late response.

Answer (score -1):

The [88E1111 Product Brief](https://www.marvell.com/transceivers/assets/Marvell-Alaska-Ultra-88E1111-GbE.pdf) says right on the cover "Integrated 10/100/1000 Ultra Gigabit Ethernet Transceiver". What more do you need?

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes, indeed it says so. But according to the datasheet it seems that this IC can only convert from SGMII to 1000BASE-LX and 10/100/1000 numbers refer to copper mode (10BASE-TX/100BASE-TX/1000BASE-TX). Here is the link to the datasheet [link](http://www.cexiinc.com/cexilib/CEXI_CAD_Footprint_Data/PDF's/Desc/MV-S100649-00H_88E1111_Datasheet.pdf)